# Toggle between two states in react

Tags: javascript, react.js, state

I have two `fetch` calls which updates the state. And I have two buttons. One makes a fetch call, another calls `componentDidMount()`.

The first fetch call is in `componentDidMount()`.

The second is On "All Time Sort" button click with `handleSortRecent()`.

On "Recent Sort" button click, I want to show the previous informatin fetched in `componentDidMount`. To achieve this
I am calling the `componentDidMount()` method itself from `handleSortRecent()` method.

Is there a better way to do this without using `Redux`?

```js
const API = "https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      dataRecent : [],
      dataAlltime : []
    }

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleSortRecent = this.handleSortRecent.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(API+"recent")
      .then( response => response.json() )
      .then( data => this.setState( { dataRecent: data } ) );
  }

  handleClick () {
    fetch(API+"alltime")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({dataRecent:data}))
  }

  handleSortRecent() {
    this.componentDidMount();
  }

  render() {
    const arrRecentList = this.state.dataRecent;

    return (
      <div className="App">
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>All Time Sort</button>
      <button onClick={this.handleSortRecent}>Recent Sort</button>
      {
        arrRecentList.map(data =>
          <div key={data.username}>
            <img src={data.img} width="50px" alt="" />
            <a href={"https://www.freecodecamp.org/"+data.username} target="_blank">{data.username}</a>
            <span> - </span>
            <span>{data.recent}</span>
            <span> - </span>
            <span>{data.alltime}</span>
          </div>
        )
      }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: [An SO question on saving previous state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44409611/how-to-save-previous-state-page-data-before-going-to-another-page-in-react-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's strange that you would call `this.componentDidMount`. I have not seen this before. Either way, what if you created an indicator in your state that declared what should be shown? For example:

```
this.state = {
  dataRecent : [],
  dataAlltime : [],
  display: "recent"
}
```

Then inside of your render function you can choose what gets displayed.

```
this.state.display === 'recent' 
  ? this.state.dataRecent.map...
  : this.state.dataAlltime.map...
```

I would create two functions that handle getting both sets of data.

```
getAlltimeData() => {
   fetch(API+"alltime")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ dataRecent:data }))
}

getRecentData() => {
   fetch(API+"recent")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ dataRecent:data }))
}
```

You can then call both of them when the component mounts.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.getAlltimeData();
  this.getRecentData();
}
```

At this point you have the data you need. What you don't have is a click handler to switch between recent and all time.

```
handleRecentClick() {
  this.setState({ display: 'recent' });
}

handleAlltimeClick() {
  this.setState({ display: 'allTime' });
}
```

Pass those to the buttons that change state respectively.

```
 <button onClick={this.handleRecentClick}>All Time Sort</button>
 <button onClick={this.handleAlltimeClick}>Recent Sort</button>
```

Make sure to bind your functions in the constructor like you did with the others.